# Is it possible to get just the price from a specific day?

Tags: python, python-3.x, yahoo-finance, yfinance

This is what I have done so far:

```
import yfinance as yf
import pandas as pd
print(yf.download("META", start="2023-08-14", end="2023-08-15")['Adj Close'])

Output:
Date
2023-08-14    306.190002
Name: Adj Close, dtype: float64
```

I was hoping to just get the price from the specific day 14/8/23 but I get some other information. Is there an alternative approach that I can use to get just the price from a specific day? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this should work!

```
x= yf.download("META", start="2023-08-14", end="2023-08-15")['Adj Close'][0]
```

also if you would have only one row always in `x` variable, you can use iloc

```
data=yf.download("META", start="2023-08-14", end="2023-08-15")
x=data.iloc[0]['Adj Close']
```

[image]